# Entity Framework 6, include field from parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have child entity, and want to include parent field. Query is simple

```
var item = db.Events
    .Where(e => e.Id == eventId)
    .Include(e => e.EventItems)
    .Include(e => e.ParentObject)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

However instead of loading whole ParentObject with its complex children, I want only one of it's fields. How should I do this, and do I need to add that field to child entity (right now I have whole parent)

```
public class EventBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentObject")]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Select(), and an anonymous type.  See [Projection Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/projection-operations)

```
var item = db.Events
    .Where(e => e.Id == eventId)
    .Include(e => e.EventItems)
    .Select(e => new {Event=e, ParentDesc=e.Parent.Desc})
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: So there is no (easy) way without Select? I have dozen properties, I was hoping I can avoid that..

Comment: You want to include a dozen parent properties, but don't want the whole parent entity?

Comment: In EF6, Includes are ignored when the query ends in a projection. Nevertheless, a projection is the way to go, but all data to be be included should be mentioned in the projection.

Comment: Sorry, just saw that whole object is mapped. Is there a way to avoid anonymous, to pass object from Repository?

Answer (score 3):

One of the slower parts of database queries is the transfer of data from the database to your local process. Therefore it is very wise not to select any properties you don't plan to use.

Therefore, whenever you see an Include, reconsider your statement. The Include is not the best way for your selections, because it transfers more data than you'll actually use.

Consider for instance a Teacher and Students. The Teacher has a primary key, every Student of this Teacher has a foreign key with a value equal to the Teacher's primary key.

If you'd use `Include` to fetch Teachers and their Students, then all foreign keys will be transferred to local memory, which is quite a waste, because you know they all equal the Teacher's primary key.

**Back to your question**

So you want some properties of the one-and-only event with eventId, you also want some properties of the parentObject of this event, and you want (some) properties of all its EventItems.

Easy! Use Select, and make sure that you only select the properties you really plan to use

```
var result = db.Events                   // from all events
    .Where(event => event.Id == eventId) // take only the ones with Id == eventId
    .Select(event => new                 // from every remaining event,
    {                                    // select the following properties:
        // select only the properties you plan to use, for instance:
        Name = event.Name,
        Description = event.Description,

        // from the one and only parent, select the properties you plan to use
        Parent = new
        {
            Name = event.ParentObject.Name,
            Security = event.ParentObject.Security, 
        },

        EventItems = event.EventItems
            .Where(eventItem => eventItem.Severity > high)
            .Select(eventItem => new
            {
                 // again: only the properties you use!
            })
            .ToList(),
    })
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: I need just one field from parent, so I was hoping there was easier way. But your code just gave me the idea to make Dto with parent field and whole Event object. That ... Parent = new {...} was crucial, I forgot I could chain subobjects!

Comment: If you only need one Parent field, just name it: ParentName = event.ParentObject.Name, no need to do Parent = new {...} I only wrote that to show that it is easy if yo want to group all Parent items together

Comment: Unfortunately this code runs in repository so I cannot return anonymous object. Your Parent gave me idea to return whole Event as subobject, and ParentName as field of Dto.